# How to hack IPB to update twitter account with every new topic?

Tags: php, twitter

I have been given a task to enable existing Invision Power Board Forum to update Twitter account whenever a new topic is created.

I should probably mention that I've already done this to other custom CMS software of the same client. And because it was custom built software it was possible to hack the code.

In this particular task that is not an option because of the potential updating issues.

How do you suggest this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see correctly, IPB has an RSS export option.
You could set up a cron job that checks the RSS feed every x minutes, and creates a tweet if it finds new items.

That would work without touching the board's code base at all.

There are several RSS parsers for PHP. [**Magpie RSS**](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) is a very popular one.